# How to forward sms using arduino uno + gsm shield

Tags: gsm

hey there I'm new to arduino. I'm working on a project that needs to send an sms to get a response and forward the response to another mobile. 
What is the easiest way to do so

Comment: Why do you want to involve an arduino in this?